# What is the Id in the ARIMA model in Notes on financial risk of Privault?

Tags: econometrics, arima

I hope this is the right place to ask this question. I am studying the time series from [Privault's Notes on Financial Risks](https://personal.ntu.edu.sg/nprivault/MH8331/time_series.pdf). In the ARIMA model part I can't understand what is "I_d", it is not specifed. The section "1.2 Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average" starts with "Consider the difference operator ∇ := Id − L", if the L is the lag operator, Id it is not specified anywhere.

Comment: Moreover, why the ARIMA is first ARIMA(1,2,3) and then ARIMA(0,2,3)?

Comment: maybe it is an operator identity...

Comment: $\triangledown = I_d - L$ is the multivariate definition of the difference operator, where $I_d \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ is the $d \times d$ identity matrix. See that, in a univariate setup it reduces to $\triangledown = 1- L$ and hence $\triangledown X_t = (1-L)X_t = X_t - X_{t-1}$, where $L$ is the back-shift operator.

Comment: With regards to your second question in the comments, I believe the author wrote ARIMA(0,2,3) as a mistake, since he simulates from an ARIMA(1,2,3) as seen by his R code at p. 9.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pleb